# asp.net mvc jquery unloading loading js script when going to next selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a dropdown on top of the page by which I hide and show different forms in the page(which are preloaded) and static defined in different divs.

The different form exists in the div and based on the selection of the dropdown I hide and show the forms. The thing is that I have multiple language calenders in here (English and Pushto) . **form 1 is showing the english calender and form2 will be showing the pushto calender and maybe form3 will show again pushto calender and so on.**  The both calender have different js files to help them render on the page. the thing is that there is a conflict meaning that if i load the pushto calender it overrides the english calender and every calender becomes pushto.

So is there any way that i can load on one selection of dropdown one set of js script files and on another selection another set of js files and samely unload them as well from the dom ? or is there any other way(THERE IS NO REFRESH)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing some example code I can only make some guesses but I assume you're doing something like:

```
$('.datePicker').myDatePicker();
```

And your JS files each have different implimentations of myDatePicker. Rather than loading and unloading both files have both in the same file and either have a different function call:

```
$('engDatePicker').engDatePicker();
$('pushtoDatePicker').pushtoDatePicker();
```

Or some other data that the function uses to chose its rendering. In which case your element would have an attribute such as

```
<input type="text" class="datePicker" data-lang="pushto" />
```

Then inside your function call get the data-lang attribute and change its rendering based on the result.

Comment: you absolutely made the right guess , any suggestion where i can change the name of the function datepicker in jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js

Comment: @mazharkaunainbaig Without seeing the code you're using and what bits have been customized it's hard to give more specific advice. Can you post up the code you're using on the page and the differences between your two versions of your jquery